# Python selenium can't click a button execute script

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click a button from the Linkedin public page feed

https://www.linkedin.com/company/bbc-news/

and the button is a post's toolbar button  with 3 dots

[here is the sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuYT5.png)

and my code is

```
self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('feed-shared-control-menu__trigger artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--circle artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view')[1].scrollIntoView();")

self.browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('feed-shared-control-menu__trigger artdeco-button artdeco-button--tertiary artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--circle artdeco-dropdown__trigger artdeco-dropdown__trigger--placement-bottom ember-view')[1].click();")
```

it doesn't return any errors

please kindly help me solve this issue

Thanks in advance for any help

Note: I have already tried `webDriverwait` , `find_elements_by_class_name`

Answer (score 0):

The element has an id associated to it, so you can use that id to get the xpath of the element and then you can click it. Also, it is recommended to use the selenium click instead of the javascript executor click(which you are currently using).
Your code should be like:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ember160']//li-icon").click()
```

If you want to use javascript executor click, then your code should be like:

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ember160']//li-icon")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: thank you @sameer

but im looping through the posts.so i had to use find_elements_by_class_name instead of find_element_by_xpath and it didn't work.and so i used script executer,the code was working fine a week ago.its scrolls to the element but not clicking